# iPhone 3g and iphone 4 resolutions Best practices

Tags: iphone, graphics, ios4, screen-resolution

Our graphics guy just gave me the sliced images for an Application we're building, but he only gave me the resolution for the 960x640 iPhone 4 res.

And advised that I can just scale the images down for 3g at runtime, so the resolution/image size remains the same but it's just displayed at half size.

The question: Is this allowed when submitting to the app store, or is it a requirement to have for example:

IMAGE1@2x.PNG (460x640) - iPhone 4

IMAGE1.PNG (230x320) - iPhone 3g

For all images.

I might just do the batch conversion and have two resolutions for all images, to save maximum space.

Comment: Make him give you half-size images as well. Doing it at runtime is not efficient, images do not always scale perfectly and should require his sign-off.

Comment: Oh so true! good point, I just realized some of the images weren't going to be divisible by 2. I've got him on the job now. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's allowed, but obviously the images will occupy four times as much RAM on the older devices than they otherwise would, having four times the pixels. While the iPhone 4 has 512mb of RAM, the 3G and the original have just 128mb. Though assuming you are dealing with memory warnings correctly and everything will still fit, the main side effect will be performance issues whenever things are purged and later reloaded from disk (which, as I'm sure you're aware, is handled automatically for view controllers in NIBs). Based on empirical observations, the flash memory on pre-3GS devices is a lot slower than the later stuff so even if you're sticking with the large images it would make sense to attempt to minimise on-disk size.

Comment: Thanks mate, that clarifies things for me.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice that has worked for me is to make my retina image, then scale it down by 50%.

In order for the retina display to use the larger image, the @2x MUST be apart of the larger image. Your example is the way it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the batch scaling ahead of time for sure. If for no other reason than the iPhone chooses whether or not to display the IMAGE1.PNG or the IMAGE1@2X.PNG depending on the resolution of the screen. In your code you always just reference IMAGE1.PNG. You don't have to make any coding changes. If you scale them at runtime you will have to override all of your calls to any UIImage type of thing.

IMHO, You are likely to miss one or else Apple is likely to release a different configuration of phone that will cause you to have to rework all of your code that is checking for screen resolution.